# Function of "gazebo_ros_camera"?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Related to the answer to this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/192057/grab-single-frame-from-gazebo-camera/.
I'm trying to write a C++ program that will allow me to capture a single frame from a camera in Gazebo and will be basing it on gazebo_ros_camera based on advice from that answer. Can someone explain to me what exactly is gazebo_ros_camera supposed to do? The source code documentation didn't really explain it, and the ROS wiki page only mentions it in passing in various places.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192427/function-of-%22gazebo_ros_camera%22?/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/18898/k.-zeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a nutshell, it generates a simulated camera image by rendering the Gazebo world from the simulated camera´s viewpoint (using methods provided by the core gazebo code) and publishes the data according to standard ROS conventions to ROS topics (as described in [REP 135](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0135.html)).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/18898/k.-zeng/) on 2014-09-11**:
I see, thanks. Is it possible to write a modified version that generates an image from an actual camera in the environment, then?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-09-12**:
Yes, you could make a version that publishes only single images. Not sure how easy it is to only generate single images via the Gazebo API, but I expect that is possible.